# Regular expression in set

Tags: python, regex, set

I'd like to do the following and have the indicated line print:

```
a=set(['bye', 'hits', 'hi'])
if r'.i*' in a:
  print "This is what I want to see."
else:
  print "Sadly, this is what I actually see."
```

Unfortunately, the `in` keyword is not performing a regular expression search on the set.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note that if you are past 2.6, you can use set literals, e.g: `{'bye', 'hits', 'hi'}`.

Comment: Can you join the set together into a single string, and test that?

Comment: This may work for some cases, @BillyMoon. But, since the joining characters may be matched by the regular expression, it isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 3):

sadly, you need a loop here:

```
import re
a = {'bye', 'hits', 'hi'}
if any(re.match(r'.i*',s) for s in a):
   print "see this"
```

I used `re.match`, but it's unclear whether you want that or `re.search`.

*NOTE:*
All that `r'my string'` denotes is a *raw string*, not a *regular expression*. Using a raw string ensures that the normal escape sequences (those starting with `\`) are not escaped. This is useful in regular expressions, as the `re` module also makes use of escape sequences. By using raw strings, one can avoid having to double-escape strings (e.g. `'a\\double escaped string'`).

Comment: I additionally want to point out `r""` isn't a special syntax for regular expressions, as OP may believe; it's a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), which just means backslashes are interpreted differently.

Comment: Thanks, @Cairnarvon, my beliefs were mistaken.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a bit about raw strings.

Comment: @JoelCornett -- I didn't even think that OP was mistaking raw strings with regular expressions.  I tend to use raw strings with regular expressions out of habit (even when I don't need them as is the case here).  Thanks for the edit.